# How to execute a method of a nested component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the component with form and I have the nested component with input['file']. Nested component have a method 'removeFile'. How can I execute this method when submit form?

```
// form
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <file-input></file-input>
</form>


// component "file-input"
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      removeFile() {
        // ***
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label>
      <div>
        <span @click="removeFile"></span>
      </div>
      <input type="file">
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you want to avoid doing this if possible.   Data should flow down and events should be emitted up.

That being said you can access by adding a ref to the child.  In child you add a

```
<Child ref='foo'></>
```

Then in your parent you access the component vie 'this.$refs.foo' which will have all the normal method and data stuff on the child.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs